# Rails changing config.assets.prefix does not change Javascript internal url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added `config.assets.prefix = "/endpoint"` into my application config. It changes all of the asset locations correctly.

However when I compile with `rake assets:precompile` the compiled Javascript still does AJAX requests to "/assets" rather than the new "/endpoint".

What am I missing?

Is there any way to make sure everything is calling from "/endpoint" rather than "/assets"?

Comment: check how you are generating the asset url in your views. is it hardcoded to assets or using `asset_url`?

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> for the main application code. In app/assets is where the javascript code is. Would I need to change that in all of the Javascripts in app/assets?

Comment: show the code that trigger those ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

So asset_path was not working normally. I am using Rails 4.. the following are in scss files. When they compile you see an error being thrown from application.js.

```
$assets-action-buttons_svg: url("<%= asset_path 'thing.svg' %>");
```

Does not work. 404 not found.

```
$assets-action-buttons_svg: url("/endpoint/thing.svg");
```

Does work.

The Javascripts in general are at /endpoint but there are a few AJAX requests that are hardcoded to /assets within the JS files. Clearing both of these issues resolved it.